# Cordova CLI 6.3.0 window.plugins undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I am compiling through build.phonegap.com
I am using CLI 6.3.0

In my index.html I have

`<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`

in my code I have this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


onDeviceReady = function() {
    alert(window.plugins);
    alert("try 2");
    alert(cordova.plugins);    }
```

both are undefined.

thanks

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the for specific plugin. i.e for push plugin your have to write :-

```
var pushNotification;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
});
```